Reason why native speakers don't say "make someone speechless/useless/unconscious"
Here's the link to another post of mine about the difference between render and make. There, people said native speakers say:

"render someone speechless/useless/unconscious", but not "make".

I understand that in many cases, it is what it is--language learners simply have to learn by heart fixed expressions like these. However, I feel that there might still be a reason why render, not "make", is used in these cases. I believe that there are more words apart from "speechless/useless/unconscious" that only go with "render", which means I'll be likely to use "make" incorrectly without realizing it in the future. Hopefully, there is a way to tell them apart. Thank you in advance!

None of these words have to be used with render. Render is somewhat more formal than "make speechless," "make useless," and "knock unconscious" respectively. It's a good question, but not the most useful examples.

One person found 'make someone speechless' etc. unidiomatic, but this Ngram shows that 'made him speechless' is not in fact that uncommon.

There are plenty of other verbs that often collocate with these words, like "left me speechless," or "knocked him unconscious."

Why do we say "rain hard" and not some other word?  Why do we "play" some sports, but not others?  Why are no "goals" in football "nil", but no "points" in tennis is "love".....
It's just idiom.
If you get it wrong, it is not a problem. I understand "make someone unconscious" it is perfectly clear, and you are a learner.  But over time you will want to gradually learn more and more of the idiomatic expressions, and the word that colocates with "unconscious" is "render".
The main point is, you don't need worry too much about this. There is no way to predict it and you have to acquire knowledge gradually.

If you say "It was raining strong, and so we couldn't play our boxing match, and agreed to call it nil-nil." I will understand you!

I understand that it doesn't matter that much when it comes to delivering a message, but I'm preparing for a speaking and writing test, so unfortunately, every unnatural sentence counts.

Actually it's the other way round,  every well formed and every idiomatic sentence counts.  You get marked positively for using accurate grammar, a wide range of vocabulary, and  so on.  You don't start with a perfect score and lose marks for mistakes. (check the IELTS marking guidelines)
